# layer_input Shape for (three-dimensional) Panel Data

Tags: r, machine-learning, keras, neural-network, panel-data

I have a balanced monthly panel data set from 2006-01 to 2019-12 and I want to use its 132 features to predict stock returns (RET) of next month. I have 2537 individual stocks per month, leaving me with a three-dimensional data set of stocks x features x months.

| Firm | Month | RET | Feature1 | Feature2 | Feature3 | ... |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2006-01 | ... |  |  |  |  |
| 1 | 2006-02 |  |  |  |  |  |
| 1 | 2006-03 |  |  |  |  |  |
| ... | ... |  |  |  |  |  |
| 2 | 2006-01 |  |  |  |  |  |
| 2 | 2006-02 |  |  |  |  |  |
| 2 | 2006-03 |  |  |  |  |  |
| ... | ... |  |  |  |  |  |

However, I receive an error regarding my layer_input specification of shape = c(2537, 132). As far as I'm informed, the batch_size, in my case the time dimension or months is left out from the shape specification, leaving me with shape = c(# of stocks, # of features).

The error says:
"ValueError: Input 0 of layer "model_6" is incompatible with the layer: expected shape=(None, 2537, 132), found shape=(None, 132)"

Can anyone help me to correctly set my layer_input shape in my panel data case?

Here's my R code:

```
train_data_panel <- data[year(data$yyyymm) >= 2007 & year(data$yyyymm) <= 2016, ]
valid_data_panel <- data[year(data$yyyymm) %in% c(2017, 2018), ]
test_data_panel <- data[year(data$yyyymm) == 2019, ]

train_dataX <- as.matrix(train_data_panel[, -(1:3)])  # Exclude permno, yyyymm, and RET columns
train_dataY <- as.matrix(train_data_panel$RET)

valid_dataX <- as.matrix(valid_data_panel[, -(1:3)])
valid_dataY <- as.matrix(valid_data_panel$RET)

test_dataX <- as.matrix(test_data_panel[, -(1:3)])
test_dataY <- as.matrix(test_data_panel$RET)


input_layer <- layer_input(shape = c(2537, 132))

hidden_layer1 <- input_layer %>%
  layer_dropout(rate = 0.4, seed = seed) %>%
  layer_dense(units = 32, activation = "relu",
              kernel_initializer = initializer_random_normal(mean = 0, stddev = 0.01, seed = seed),
              kernel_regularizer = regularizer_l1(0.001))

hidden_layer2 <- hidden_layer1 %>%
  layer_dropout(rate = 0.3, seed = seed) %>%
  layer_dense(units = 16, activation = "relu",
              kernel_regularizer = regularizer_l1(0.001))

hidden_layer3 <- hidden_layer2 %>%
  layer_dropout(rate = 0.2, seed = seed) %>%
  layer_dense(units = 8, activation = "relu",
              kernel_regularizer = regularizer_l1(0.001))

hidden_layer4 <- hidden_layer3 %>%
  layer_dropout(rate = 0.1, seed = seed) %>%
  layer_dense(units = 4, activation = "relu",
              kernel_regularizer = regularizer_l1(0.001))

output_layer <- hidden_layer4 %>%
  layer_dense(units = 1, activation = "linear")

model <- keras_model(inputs = input_layer, outputs = output_layer)

# Compile model
model %>% compile(
  loss = "mse",
  optimizer = tf$keras$optimizers$legacy$Adam(
            learning_rate = 0.01, 
            decay = 0.01),
  metrics = c("mae")
)

# Fit model
history <- model %>% fit(
  x = train_dataX,
  y = train_dataY,
  validation_data = list(validation_dataX, validation_dataY),
  epochs = 100,
  batch_size = 32,
  verbose = 1,
  callbacks = list(
    callback_early_stopping(
      monitor = "val_loss",
      min_delta = 0.0001,
      patience = 10,
      verbose = 1,
      mode = "min",
      restore_best_weights = TRUE)
  )
)
```

when I leave out the '2537' from shape and only use layer_input(shape = c(132)) it runs, however then I'm disregarding my panel data structure by dropping the cross-section dimension.